# How to run bat file in different directory

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, path

I have a bat file which runs a java programm called `Systemm.java`, located within a package called `tp3`

My file organization is as follows

```
.
├── src
    ├── tp3
    │   ├── Systemm.java
    │   ├── Communication.java
    │   └── exec_server.bat
    └── teste.bat
```

So, my main problem is, I'm using teste.bat to run my class Systemm.java. And this bat works fine.

What I am also trying to do is call exec_server.bat in java.

Sequentially:

- teste.bat runs Systemm.java
- Systemm.java has an instance of class Communication.java
- This instance runs a method that should run exec_server.bat

`Communication executeServer() method`

```
public void executeServer() {
        try {
            // Path 
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"\" tp3\exec_server.bat");
            p.waitFor();
            System.out.println("I finished running your server");
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

However when I run my programm, this method displays this message on cmd

[image]

I am pretty much the newbie exploring cmd and bat files, so I am really confused as to what am I doing wrong.

Thank you so much for any help in advance!

P.S: I' calling cmd on the src directory, and `exec_server.bat`  only echos the message "Hi there!" on cmd

Answer (score 0):

Please try with by giving full path:

```
  Process p = null;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start D:\\practice\\P1\\samp.bat ");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```